# Devise uses app's layout but ignores ApplicationController methods and filters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

Devise is using the host application's layout but not the controller methods and before_ filters specified in the ApplicationController. I get an error that alludes to the fact that @sitemap is nil in this part of my layout: `<%= select_tag :site_navigation, options_for_select(@sitemap), prompt: "Quick Navigation" %>`

---

### **manager/application_controller.rb**

```
module Manager
    class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

        protect_from_forgery
        before_filter :load_sitemap

        ... more code here ...


    protected

        # This is run every time a request is made...but
        # it doesn't get run by Devise's SessionsController
        # even though Devise uses the layout which uses
        # @sitemap and fails if it is nil
        def load_sitemap
            return [] unless Manager.configuration.master?
            @sitemap = {
                "Albums" => albums_path,
                "Add Wine Award" => new_award_path,
                "Businesses" => businesses_path,
                "Cash Tracking" => cash_trackers_path,
                "Events" => events_path,
                "Locations" => locations_path,
                "Medals" => medals_path,
                "New Timesheet" => new_timesheet_path,
                "Recipes" => recipes_path,
                "Reviews" => reviews_path,
                "Wines" => wines_path,
                "Wine Competitions" => competitions_path
            }
        end
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably a name-spacing problem based on your use of the `Manager` module.

devise's `user_controller` will inherit from `ApplicationController`.
Not `Manager::ApplicationController`

If you want devise to run your before filter, you need to put it into the root-level `ApplicatonController` instead.

Comment: Ah, you're right. Luckily my master app is a thin shell around the Manager engine. Telling the app to inherit it's ApplicationController from Manager::ApplicationController solved the issue. As for slave apps, I might have to do some digging; hopefully not.